# GPX File simulation on device without being connected to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, simulation, gpx

We have option to simulate device location via .gpx files when the app runs in the debug mode. If we edit the scheme and set the default location to the .gpx file then we can get the .gpx location on launch time as well.

**Scenario:** I have a .gpx file which traverses through a series of waypoints. The traversal runs fine and the didUpdateLocation() gets fired within the set time interval. But all this happens when the app runs in debug mode connected to Xcode.

**Problem:** ***How can we allow simulation through the waypoints even device is not in debugging mode?*** It would be of great help to testers as well as for the developers to have this feature.

**.gpx file used:**

[Drop Box Link to the .gpx file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6lwudgpwwxj78t/New%20York%20City%20Marathon.gpx?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

GPX simulation is just available with xCode debugging i.e. either simulator or device debugging. 
In case you install application with Location simulation and then disconnect your device without stopping build from xCode then device will remain in the GPX file first location. You can cross check this by opening MAP. 
But location updates will not be there even if you specify time tag in GPX file.

Answer (score 1):

U can try using the mock location and swizzling the Location Manager delegates.
One of the good article about it `https://hackernoon.com/simulating-user-location-and-navigation-route-on-iphone-without-xcode-761f06905f1c`
I didnt try it..
May be u can give a try about it.